# how can i split couchbase document which exceeds 20MB of size? return message = ValueTooLarge, Success = false Couchbase 3.0.3 .net 4.5.1 C#

Tags: c#, couchbase, nosql

Document size having more than 20MB physical size, number of characters> 22000000
please see below code

```
var jsonDataRow = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(objXML, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
var document = new Document<string>
    {
        Id = "RR",
        Content = jsonDataRow
    };

var upsert = bucket.Upsert(document);
```

Comment: What does your document look like? Can you break it into smaller pieces (refer vs embed) and then do separate look-ups for the individual parts?

Comment: Basically my document is embed document. PSB
{
    "_index": "version_poc",
    "_type": "couchbaseDocument",
    "_id": "INVOICE_40827_2",
  {
   "Document_Type": "INVOICE",
   "Document_ID": "INVOICE_40827_2",   
   "INVOICE_LINE": [
    {
     "Document_Type": "INVOICE_LINE",
     "Document_ID": "LINE_94826_2",     
     .
     .
     ]
    }
    "INVOICE_LINE": [
    {
     "Document_Type": "INVOICE_LINE",
     "Document_ID": "INVOICE_LINE_94920_2",     
     .
     .
     ]
    }    
    .
    .
    .
  }
}

Here 'n' number of Invoice_Line(s) are present

Comment: 1) The requirement is to use embed document.
2) It is nested document, splitting of document is also difficult at application site,
3)Even if i split the document how can i map these documents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a parent document which holds the keys to the child documents:

```
{
   "id": "parent_doc_1",
   "children": [ "child_doc1", "child_doc2"]
}
```

The child docs are then stored separately:

```
{
    "id": "child_doc1",
    "parent_id": "parent_doc_1"
}
```

and

```
{
  "id": "child_doc2",
  "parent_id": "parent_doc_1"
}
```

Then pull the parent document and get the child keys (id) and fetch those using a bulk Get using the SDK of your choice. Something like this:

```
var parent = await bucket.GetAsync<dynamic>("parent_doc_id");
if (parent.Success)
{
   var children = await bucket.GetAsync<dynamic>(parent.Value.children);
   //do stuff
}
```

That's not real code, but you should be able to the idea here.